# Console error ".. undefined is not a function" regarding .has()?

Tags: jquery

I am receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have several versions of jQuery defined within the `head`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js"></script>
```

And the error is being called on two different instances where I use the `.has()` method. I know the code itself is error-free because it does what I want. I know this probably means one of jQuery references is outdated but to my knowledge this method was added in 1.4.2 so I don't see how that's possible.

Can the noconflict file have anything to do with this? I can add more info. as needed just let me know.

Comment: Why do you use several versions of jQuery ???

Comment: this is... well. scary.

Comment: What are `js/jquery-noconflict.js` and `js/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: A file with `jQuery.noConflict();` in it.

Comment: @Jason You need to **not** have multiple versions of jQuery. What/why are you even can't what?

Comment: @NickDugger: That's obvious to me, but again isn't this a method added in 1.4.2? Then why should it matter in this instance!?

Comment: ... just remove 1.4.2

Comment: yea my first course of action would be to remove the last two scripts, they are conflicting with eachother

Comment: let me give that a try.

Comment: Why do you have `jquery-noconflict.js` loaded twice?  If you have *two* `jQuery.noConflict();` lines, then how do you access each jQuery instance?  You only need to call it once after both jQuerys are loaded.  `jQuery.noConflict();` will return you the `jQuery` object of the 2nd one and restore the global `$` to the 1st one (if you pass `true` it will also reset the global `jQuery` variable).  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict#example-4

Answer (score 1):

If the last script is a noconflict jQuery, then is redefining $  to jQuery and therefore, $ is undefined

Comment: as rlemon says, cant help you further then, im quite scared